# Map marker animation working in Firefox but not in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, transform, css-animations

I've been trying to get a simple CSS animation to work. Check [this link](http://minimalistarray.com/contact.html) here for the demo.

In Firefox it works fine, but I can't get it to work in Chrome/Safari.

My CSS code is ~

```
.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add -webkit- to your animation and transform. Check this fiddle in chrome its working http://jsfiddle.net/Gt4rP/2/

CSS

```
.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
    transform: rotateX(55deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
    animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
```